# rqt AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I am trying to run rqt_gragh as the tutorials/understanding topics said. But when I run that I got following error.

```
   human@pangaea:~$ rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/rqt_gui/rqt_gui", line 8, in <module>
    p = r.get_path('rqt_gui')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 188, in get_path
    self._update_location_cache()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 171, in _update_location_cache
    list_by_path(self._manifest_name, path, cache)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 68, in list_by_path
    resource_name = root.findtext('name').strip(' \n\r\t')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

I would really appreciate if anybody can tell me how to figure it out.Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196220/rqt-attributeerror:-%27nonetype%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27strip%27/) by [duanxiaobin](https://answers.ros.org/users/20623/duanxiaobin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-10-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-10-29**:
It looks like you have an invalid package.xml / manifest.xml somewhere on your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Do you have any custom packages in your environment? which are not installed from Debian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I make a mistake about setup environment. Before that I throught I only need type `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`one time.So I open a new terminal not type that, then `rosrun rqt-gragh rqt-gragh`the error occur.**I should
setup the environment correctly.**

---

Originally posted by [duanxiaobin](https://answers.ros.org/users/20623/duanxiaobin/) with karma: 36 on 2014-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2